# Flask SQLAlchemy - order results by weight / score, based on number of matching many-to-many objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the following models:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    taxonomy = db.Column(db.Unicode(), nullable=False)

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'tag',
        'polymorphic_on': taxonomy,
        'order_by': name
    }


class FooTag(Tag):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'foo'
    }


class BarTag(Tag):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'bar',
    }


class Profile(db.Model):
    foo_tags = db.relationship(
        "FooTag",
        secondary=profiles_tags,
        secondaryjoin="and_(Tag.id==profiles_tags.c.tag_id, Tag.taxonomy=='foo')",
        uselist=True,
        lazy='dynamic'
    )

    bar_tags = db.relationship(
        "BarTag",
        secondary=profiles_tags,
        secondaryjoin="and_(Tag.id==profiles_tags.c.tag_id, Tag.taxonomy=='bar')",
        uselist=True,
        lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

Is there anyway that I can filter `Profile` objects by a set of `Tag`s, and then order the results by the number of matching `Tag`s? ie.

```
foo_tags=[2, 4, 6]
bar_tags=[8, 22, 14] 

results = Profile.join(Profile.foo_tags).filter(FooTag.id.in_(foo_tags)).\
    join(Profile.bar_tags).filter(BarTag.id.in_(bar_tags)).\
    paginate(1, 20)
```

Where the order of `results` is determined by how many matching `foo_tags`/ `bar_tags` were found on each returned object?

This is `Python==2.7`, `Flask==0.12.2`, `SQLAlchemy==1.1.11`, `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using joined inheritance, and so `FooTag` and `BarTag` reference the same id domain of `Tag`, there is no need to separately join and filter based on `foo_tags` and `bar_tags`. Instead you could join `Profile` and `Tag`, or even just `Profile` and `profiles_tags`, filter, and group by a key such as `Profile.id`, if it has such a primary key (the example in the question is lacking in this regard):

```
results = Profile.query.\
    join(profiles_tags).\
    filter(profiles_tags.c.tag_id.in_(foo_tags + bar_tags)).\
    group_by(Profile.id).\
    order_by(func.count(), Profile.id)
```

The profile id is included as a tiebreaker in the ordering, so that you get deterministic pagination.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution, feels so obvious now. Thank you!